# Unexpected closing tag of div element

Tags: html, css

I want to insert a div inside the table element as the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cs5p08nu/3/)

Code:

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">User</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-center">Test</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredItems$ | async; index as i">
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>
            Test
            </td>
            <td>
              <ul class="timeline" id="timeline">
                <li class="li complete">
                  <div class="timestamp">
                    <span class="author">Abhi Sharma</span>
                    <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="status">
                    <h4> Shift Created </h4>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="li complete">
                  <div class="timestamp">
                    <span class="author">PAM Admin</span>
                    <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="status">
                    <h4> Email Sent </h4>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="li complete">
                  <div class="timestamp">
                    <span class="author">Aaron Rodgers</span>
                    <span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="status">
                    <h4> SIC Approval </h4>
                  </div>
                </li>
               
               </ul>      
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

But it is returning an error of unexpected closing tag.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected
> closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed
> by another tag.

I can not find why, because all my div are closed, someone knows what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing the span tag in the following line in each of the li's

```
<span class="date">11/15/2014<span>
```

it should be (note - **you will need to update each of the 3 instances**)

```
<span class="date">11/15/2014</span>
```

When you see the closing tag error - go through your code to check that all tags have been closed - it may not be the item that was listed in the error... js tries to infer closing tags when they are missing and the one identified may simply be at the end of that guess.

Comment: @Jesus There is a page where you can find how to check errors by yourself : https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input